# norm 2 optimization solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

How can I reach the solution of the following optimization problem?

[image]

The solution is

[image]

Comment: From what paper is this? What is $\mathcal C$? Where's your work?

Comment: from the paper "online dictionary learning for sparse coding" written by Julien Mairal   C = {D ∈ R^m×k s.t. ∀j = 1, . . . , k, transpose(dj)*dj ≤ 1}.

Comment: As Rodrigo mentioned, you have better chance of receiving an answer if you show what have you tried and where exactly are you stuck.

Comment: thanks for your attention,i is column of x,t is column of matrix X,in the paper mentioned that by using simple algebra,it is easy to show that second image gives the solution of equation (9), I want to know how can reach solution of equation (9)

Comment: Please use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a partial answer to get you started.

From [the matrix cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf):
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial D} \text{tr}(D^TB_t) = B_t
$$ $$\frac{\partial}{\partial D} \text{tr}(D^TD A_t) = DA_t^T + DA_t $$
Next, note that $A_t$ is symmetric since it is comprised of self outer products.

Then, we want to minimize:
$$
\mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{t}\left[ \frac{1}{2}\text{tr}\left( D^TDA_t \right) -\text{tr}(D^TB_t)\right]
$$
Let us compute its derivative with respect to $D$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial D}\mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{t}\left[  DA_t  -B_t \right]
$$
Just looking at the $j$th column:
$$
\nabla_j \,\mathcal{E} = \frac{1}{t}(Da_j - b_j)
$$
So, if we wanted to do gradient descent, it should look something like:
$$
d_j \leftarrow d_j - \xi_r\, \nabla_j\,\mathcal{E}
$$
So notice that:
$$
d_j - \xi_r\, \nabla_j\,\mathcal{E} = \xi_r\left( \frac{1}{t}(b_j - Da_j) \right) + d_j
$$
which is close to the form you want.

Of course, they are correcting this to something more sophisticated.

Comment: thanks for the answer. another question is that in first picture how can we reach the second line from the first one?